# Capture packages from an android application that uses tls

Tags: android, ssl, https, tcpdump, netcat

I can intercept packets on a device with root with **tcpdump** and **netcat**, but I encounter problems with decrypting **TLS** packets with **wireshark**.

1. Is there a way in my android device to share decryption keys when an https connection is established? Do you know any apps?
2. Is there anything that allows me to create SSLKEYLOGFILE in android like in windows?  Or something that allows me to decrypt the app data of my device. I've already tried frida and proxy for SSL pinning but it doesn't work on some apps.

Thank you so much for the help and I'm sorry for my English